# VB.Net datatable/dataview sort error

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

First, I am not a programmer, I self-thought myself VBA and then VB.net and read a few books on the subject but I am far from an expert, sometimes I get lost in the terminology so please be patient with me.

I have two datatables that I want to sort. They are very similar and contain similar data but one if for High Index data, the other for Low Index data.  They are loaded from parsed out text file and are bound to two different datagridviews.

I think I got the sorting part down but the high index data table generates an error every time I try to run the code. While the names (columns, tables, etc.) are different, both the low and high index tables are very similar and should for all instance and purposes behave the same.

Sample code:

```
    Dim dtvSorted1 As DataView
    Dim dtvSorted2 As DataView

    dtvSorted1 = New DataView(tblLowData)
    dtvSorted1.Sort = "Point Low ASC"
    grdLowData.DataSource = dtvSorted1

    dtvSorted2 = New DataView(tblHighData)
    dtvSorted2.Sort = "Point High ASC"
    grdHighData.DataSource = dtvSorted2 <- Stops on this line only.
```

The code ALWAYS generates an error on the last line of code.  The Error it generates is as follows:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Child list for field tblHighData cannot be created.

I've been looking for an answer to this for the past 2 days and cannot find a suitable answer that fixes the problem.  I've tried renaming every element possible to see if this was an errant "." causing issues, the problem persists.  What I find difficult to understand is that, except for the names of the table and grid elements, both datable and grids are identical and (should) behave the same way!

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: The issue is likely because your field name has a space. I don't know what you need to use for the `sort` method but try single quotes or square brackets [] around the field name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The Sort function works fine, I can see that the data is properly sorted in the the data visualizer, it's the last line that is giving a problem. I've also tried what you suggested, no luck...

Comment: So, if you comment out the sort line you don't get the error? Could you add the full stack trace at the point of the error?

Comment: I've figured it out! Thanks for the help.  Both datagridviews were on different tabs of a tab control.  Not sure why but it would not set the data source to the dataview unless the tab was selected.  I had to programmaticaly switch to the other tab before trying to bind the data source.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Each datagridviews was on a different tab of a tab control. Not sure why but it would not set the data source to the dataview unless that tab was selected. I had to programmatically switch to the other tab before trying to bind the data source.

Comment: Please explain how you solved your problem.  Your contribution could be valuable  for future Seekers.